# In spark-shell, how to load jars and importing corresponding packages correctly?

Tags: scala, shell, graph, spark-graphx

I'm sorry for that I'm a new bee, so this question may not ask well.

I'm doing practice about the GraphX  of Spark, following what the book 《 Apache Spark Graph Processing 》（Chapter 3 - 《Graph Analysis and Visualization》）wrritten.

In Spark-shell ,after using "spark-shell --jars" to load jars and importing corresponding packages, it responds "object graphstream is not a member of package org" .

Let me show you the details.

1.1 The result after I typed in 
./bin/spark-shell --jars lib/breeze-viz_2.10-0.9.jar :
[The console information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gacYo.png)

1.2 The result after I typed in 
./bin/spark-shell --jars lib/breeze-viz_2.10-0.9.jar, lib/breeze_2.10-0.9.jar (it's the same as the picture above):
[The console information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yb9kl.png)

1.3 The result after I typed in 
'./bin/spark-shell --jars lib/breeze-viz_2.10-0.9.jar, lib/breeze_2.10-0.9.jar, lib/gs-core-1.2.jar , lib/gs-ui-1.2.jar , lib/jcommon-1.0.16.jar , lib/jfreechart-1.0.13.jar ' :
it's the same as the picture above.

2. The result after I typed in 'import org.graphstream.graph.{Graph => GraphStream}' is:

   ```
   scala> import org.graphstream.graph.{Graph => GraphStream}

   <console>:25: error: object graphstream is not a member of package org
          import org.graphstream.graph.{Graph => GraphStream}
                   ^
   ```

what can I do to solve such problem

how to check if the jars have been loaded correctly?

Comment: What version of Spark? In newer versions there's a `--packages` option for `spark-shell`. You set it like: `--packages org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.10:0.8.2.0,com.gensler:scalavro-core_2.10:0.6.2,org.apache.avro:avro:1.8.0`

Comment: I have Spark 1.6 but when I try to load graphstream jars with --jars, I get the same error message

Comment: I don't think this is an answer, but try to do: ./bin/spark-shell --jars lib/gs-core-1.3.jar, lib/gs-ui-1.3.jar, lib/breeze-viz_2.11-0.12.jar, lib/breeze_2.11-0.12.jar

Comment: @user299791 what's the difference between your answer "lib/gs-core-1.3.jar, lib/gs-ui-1.3.jar, lib/breeze-viz_2.11-0.12.jar, lib/breeze_2.11-0.12.jar"  and mine?

Comment: I don't know that's why I don't think it's an answer, but as a matter of fact, when I changed the order on my system, it suddenly worked